# Grails NPE on all requests to controller until recompile without change to code

Tags: grails

I'm using Grails 2.0.0. I've started using the webflow plug-in a couple days ago and today ran into some trouble. When I run the application and hit the controller that uses webflow, I get a NullPointerException. If I reload, I get the same. If I add a space to the controller source file (or any change at all, just need to force a recompile) and save with run-app still going, Grails recompiles the controller and subsequent requests work without error.  Unfortunately I don't know  when the error first came up.  I haven't been able to trace the error back to a particular change I made.

How can I dig deeper on this? Why would re-compiling a controller at run time fix an NPE?

Here's the controller code that I can use to reproduce the issue:

```
class ServicesController { 
  def index() { 
    redirect(action: "request") 
  } 

  def requestFlow = { 
    selectAssessments { 
      on("next") { 
      }.to("productInfo") 
      on("cancel").to("finish") 
    } 
  }
}
```

And here's the console log:

```
| Error 2012-03-18 21:43:11,272 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /project/services/request 
Stacktrace follows: 
Message: null 
   Line | Method 
->> 886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   908 | run     in     '' 
^   680 | run . . in java.lang.Thread 
| Error 2012-03-18 21:43:13,261 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-4] ERROR servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet  - HandlerInterceptor.afterCompletion threw exception 
Message: No value for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@57c40e95] bound to thread ["http-bio-8080"-exec-4] 
   Line | Method 
->> 886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   908 | run     in     '' 
^   680 | run . . in java.lang.Thread 
| Error 2012-03-18 21:43:14,199 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-5] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /project/services/request - parameters: 
execution: e1s1 
Stacktrace follows: 
Message: null 
   Line | Method 
->> 886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   908 | run     in     '' 
^   680 | run . . in java.lang.Thread 
| Error 2012-03-18 21:43:14,262 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-5] ERROR servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet  - HandlerInterceptor.afterCompletion threw exception 
Message: No value for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@57c40e95] bound to thread ["http-bio-8080"-exec-5] 
   Line | Method 
->> 886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   908 | run     in     '' 
^   680 | run . . in java.lang.Thread
```

From target/stacktrace.log:

```
2012-03-23 22:00:33,470 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-3] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.GrailsOpenSessionInViewInterceptor.postHandle(GrailsOpenSessionInViewInterceptor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.WebRequestHandlerInterceptorAdapter.postHandle(WebRequestHandlerInterceptorAdapter.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(GrailsDispatcherServlet.java:342)
...  
2012-03-23 22:00:33,490 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-3] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
...
2012-03-23 22:00:36,725 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-3] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No value for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@12653c7e] bound to thread ["http-bio-8080"-exec-3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:209)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.afterCompletion(OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.java:211)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have been fixed by creating a new controller of a different name using grails create-controller, and copying the code over from the old controller to the new one. Was unable to find root cause of the exception. 'grails clean' did not fix it, by the way.